# CF (If..headerlocation)?

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to make a CF code that will select the row "welcome" from the table 
"users" where username = #session.username#.

If "welcome" = 1 then i want it to direct the user to /me/index.cfm

I am new at CF, how would this be possible.

Comment: Since you mentioned headers in your title, I'll point out that, whilst [**cflocation**](http://cfdocs.org/cflocation) handles location headers, you always use [**cfheader**](http://cfdocs.org/cfheader) for generic HTTP headers, for example `<cfheader statuscode="302" statustext="Moved Temporarily" />` and `<cfheader name="Location" value="http://new-url" />`

Comment: CF8 added the ability to set the status code as an attribute of the <cflocation> tag

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you need to do a DB query by the sounds of it:

```
<cfquery name="getWelcome" datasource="yourDSN">
  SELECT welcome
  FROM users
  WHERE username = <cfqueryparam value="#session.username#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"> 
</cfquery>
```

Then you need to check the value from the query, and also taking into account the fact that the query might not find anything at all.

```
<cfif NOT getWelcome.recordcount>
<!--- do something, maybe redirect to the login page --->

</cfif>

<cfif getWelcome.welcome EQ 1>
  <cflocation url="/me/index.cfm">
</cfif>
```

The most important thing here is the use of cfqueryparam to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @Brooke - just a note, the example above is excellent but it assumes that the query "getWelcome" will only return 1 row. That's something to keep in mind. The code that says if _getWelcom.welcome EQ 1_ is only going to analyze the _first_ row of the query that's returned. If there's more than one row the rest of them will be ignored. I realize your query is probably _designed_ for only 1 row so that's cool. I'm just pointing it out. :)

Comment: Good point. I hope that usernames are unique in the users table!

Answer (score 0):

You can write like :

```
<cfif welcome EQ 1>
<cflocation url="/me/index.cfm">
</cfif>
```

Comment: 'template' is not an attribute of the cflocation tag